# How to filter web traffic on Google Analytics based on type of user login using Django Authorization

Tags: django, google-analytics

I have a website where I have three different login accounts on a Django site: admin, customers, and sellers. Right now, the traffic for all three accounts is being aggregated together on Google Analytics. Does anyone know how I can tag traffic from each of these accounts so I can filter on my Google Analytics account?

My two guesses are:

1. I render some type of profile name into the creation of the Google Analytics instance that would allow me to filter in Google Analytics:

   `ga('create','UA-XXXXXXXX-X','{{ profile_type }}');`
2. I create separate tracking IDs for each profile type and render those in depending on the account logged in. I don't necessarily want three different accounts on the Google Analytics side of things though, I just want to be able to filter between them. An example would be to insert this into the GA snipped when a user is logged in as an admin:

   `ga('create','UA-{{admin_ga_tracking_code}}')`

Filtering by IP is not a solution because my admins and customers are all around the world and change.

Thank you for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. I created a new property within Google Analytics and created a Universal Analytics property for each account type. You can learn more about Universal Analytic properties here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537?hl=en

I then rendered the Universal Analytic property on each base template I created for each different type of account.